# How to cluster sentences based on company names from a post(s) containing several company names using similarity metric.

Tags: python, nlp, text-mining

My corpus contains several posts having text for several companies i.e. each post contains information about several companies.

I want to cluster the information based on few company names that I can specify. Clustering should be based on some similarity matrix such as euclidean or cosine similarity.

Which algorithm to use based on company name that I can specify and which similarity method to use?

Answer (score 0):

One option is [Anchored CorEx](https://github.com/gregversteeg/corex_topic) which performs clustering with anchor words. For your problem, the anchor words would be company names.